# Facebook share description bad encoding

Tags: php, facebook, encoding

When I share a product from my page the description have bad encoding:

you can test it here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmihalko.eu%2Ffelt-destination

the page what I am trying to share:

http://mihalko.eu/felt-destination

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an `og:description` meta tag for the description and make sure it is properly UTF-8 encoded, it doesn't seem to be at the moment.

Comment: go:description not helped, in database the text is stored in utf8_bin

Comment: Its og:description not go:description and needs to be in the `<head>` of your page, should use htmlspecialchars with the UTF-8 option.